# Self-contained book about complex systems and non-linear dynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am a student at the 2nd year of a B.Sc. in Biotechnology. I started reading some papers about complex systems and nonlinear dynamics applied to economy, biology of course, climate model etc...
I would like to study theme better so i need a textbook from which i can start. I toke a calculus course and i am going to study multivariate calculus and linear algebra next months (self study).
The question is: can anyone tell me about a book which is self-contained, about complex systems and nonlinear dynamics (even with applications)? I mean: a book that has some preliminaries about linear algebra or whatever i need to study these disciplines.